# React: Need to call parent to re-render component

Tags: reactjs

I create a table with rows and sub-rows . When i delete a sub-row i need to re-render the whole component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import auth from './auth'

export class FormList extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    auth.onChange = this.updateAuth.bind(this)
    this.state = {results: []};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    auth.login();
  }

  // call to get the whole list of forms for react to re-render.
  getForms() {
    if(this.state.loggedIn) {
      $.get(call server url, function(result) {
        this.setState({
             results: result.data.forms
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }

  updateAuth(loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
     loggedIn: loggedIn
    });
    this.getForms()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getForms()
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <FormTable results={this.state.results} /> 
    )
 }
};

class FormTable extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return ( 
      <table className="forms">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Form Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th style={{width: "40px"}}></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       {this.props.results.map(function(result) {
            return <FormItem key={result.Id} data={result} />;
        })}         
      </table>
    )
  }
};

class FormItem extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr className="form_row">
          <td>{this.props.data.Name}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        {this.props.data.map(function(result) {
            return <FormTransaction key={result.Id} data={result} />;
        })} 
      </tbody>
    )
  }
};

class FormTransaction extends React.Component{

  render() { 
    return (
      <tr className="subform_row">
          <td>{this.props.data.date}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td data-enhance="false">
          <DeleteTransaction data={this.props.data.Id} />
      </tr>
    )
  }
};

class DeleteTransaction extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {Id:props.data};
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
   }

   // deletes a sub row and calls get forms to re-render the whole react.
   handleDelete(event) {
     $.ajax({
      url: server url + this.state.Id,
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result, status) {
          console.log(this);
          // need to call get forms here
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
          console.log(jqXHR);
      }
     });*/
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <i className="danger" onClick = {this.handleDelete}>X</i>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  (<FormList/>),
  document.getElementById('react-forms')
);
```

So i need to call the getforms method after delete is successful from handledelete method.

I am pretty new to react as well as using es6 . I tried extending deletetransaction to formslist and call super.getForms . But that didnt work either.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: you could try a cascading prop function call.. or you should try and use a flux/redux pattern to have an action that does that for you.

Comment: I tried passing the getForms function as a prop across components. But when the delete transaction actually calls the getforms methods, the scope of "this" object is the handletransaction method. I call "this.state.getForms()" in the handledelete method.

Comment: you should bind this to getForms initially and you can clean up a whole component to make it less cluttered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might also pass down a function from the parent component to the child component via the `props` of the child component, then upon an action of function being executed in the child component, you could simply call the function that was passed in.

For instance:

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    update: function() {
        this.setState({somethingToUpdate: "newValue"});
        console.log("updated!");
    },
    render: function() {
      <ChildComponent callBack={this.update} />
    }
})

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      <button onClick={this.props.callBack}>click to update parent</button>
    }
})
```

Comment: but this wouldn't make the parent to rerender

Comment: @Maysam you can call this.setState() inside update() to rerender ParentComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to call this.setState inside another function it will not know you are trying to set the state.

For example, in your code you have $.get( ... function (response){  ... this.setState() .. }

Because this.setState is inside function (response) **this** will point to function(response) rather than pointing to the root class.

So what you need to do is to save this inside a variable right before the $.get call.

var self = this;
and inside the function do self.setState( ... ) instead of this.setState( .. )

Hope it helps.